# Creating a Facebook page and access it via shorturl

Tags: facebook, url, short

Hey Guys, so Ive created a Facebook page, no content as yet, really, i would like to know if it is possible and if so, how do I set it to be accessible from eg: www.facebook.com/mypage ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your page needs to have at least 25 fans, before you can create a custom name for it. For more info, read the official Facebook note on [Usernames for Facebook Pages](http://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=127301830640554&sk=basic#!/note.php?note_id=383008189821).

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you should consider up-voting it and/or accepting it. This way you would give feedback to the answer author and information to other SO users on the answer usefulness.